# Get discography of an artist exactly like the overview page on musicbrainz

Tags: java, android, api, musicbrainz

I am trying to use the musicBrainz api for getting the discography of an artist using the following method: `http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/?query=artist:eminem` but i get a lot of unsorted and repeated data. I know that i can use keywords (AND, OR, etc) but i do not really know how to sort it by date or filter repeated data. Is there a way to do this in the rest call or have i to implement these sort methods in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About **repeated data**:
It sounds what you want are *release groups*, not releases. For example a certain album is one *release group* on MusicBrainz, but usually has multiple different *releases* in this group due to different editions of an album.

About **sorting**:
Unfortunately cou can't sort the data while querying the web service yet. There is a ticket for that: [MBS-5636](http://tickets.musicbrainz.org/browse/MBS-5636).
If you do want to sort the data, you have to fetch all of it and sort it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this answer help me a lot. i didn't know what were the release groups about and now i will test them